# Will an Android app only receive push notifications is the app was downloaded from the Google Play Store? (React Native Expo)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, react-native-push-notification

I'm using Expo push notifications. Push notifications work fine in Expo Go and for apps on published to the Google Play store. But when I create an APK file and download it directly onto my Android phone, NOT through the Google Play store, the push notifications I send are not received.

Will push notifications only work for apps published to the Google Play store? Or is there a way to receive push notifications for apps downloaded directly onto an Android phone without being published to the Google Play store?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to publish the app on to play store to receive push notifications

Comment: Did you test with -> https://expo.dev/notifications

Comment: @MichaelBahl Yes I did. It works in Expo Go and for apps published to the Google Play store. But it will NOT work for apk downloaded directly to the phone.

Comment: Did you check the app permission ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl What is app permission? Can you respond with that as an answer? I'll checkmark it as the answer if that fixes it. Thank you

Comment: Have you set up FCM? If not, please refer to a question I just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140907/react-native-firebase-push-notificatoins-using-expo-permission -- I just set this up a week or so ago for my app so that I could have my app respond to background notifications (you can't do/test that in Expo Go). The instructions require a bit of focus, but if you haven't done it yet, it's definitely the reason why your Expo Go app would work but your Standalone/Managed/APK build wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to import { Platform } from 'react-native'.

Also, I needed to upload Android server api key credentials which can be found in Firebase Console in your project settings under Cloud Messaging. Here is how to upload the server api key credentials in the terminal:

```
expo push:android:upload --api-key <your-token-here>
```

Documentation can be found here under "Uploading Server Credentials": https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on your android version and rom you have to open the app setting's (for me long press app icon).
2. Select settings
3. Choose notifications
4. Enable notification for this app

Comment: This was helpful. It did not fix the problem yet, but it proved there's something wrong with the permission request on APK direct download. The APK app is not requesting permission to send push notifications on the APK direct download for some reason. But it DOES request permission fine in Expo Go and in apps published to the Google or Apple app stores.