# React native firebase push notifications using expo permission

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

Can anyone help me to resolve this warning?

I am trying to send push notification using expo in React native.
I also tried to change permission from Notification to Permission but no luck.

[warning when trying to access device token for send notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U08FD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the managed flow or bare workflows?

I didn't get this exact message, but I got many that are similar. (I'm using a Managed flow). Likely culprit is a gap in your Firebase Cloud Messaging setup.

Be sure to review all the instructions expo here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/

I also added a response to an existing SO documenting some of my stumbling blocks which may be affecting you as well. That is here: [Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396012/exception-occurred-while-executing-exported-method-getdevicepushtokenasync-on-mo/69039842#69039842)

Comment: i am using bare workflows from https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/